# How to persist graphs presenting circular references in Voyage?

Tags: persistence, smalltalk, pharo

I'm having an issue I don't recall having had about half a year ago when trying out Voyage.

In my schema, a **User** has an *instVar* referencing all the **Centers** he belongs to, and a **Center** has an *instVar* referencing all of its **Users**, so when the Voyage serializer tries to serialize a user (or a center), it goes into an infinite loop trying to find the end of the reference chain and the image clogs.

I remember saving the exact same schema a while ago without a problem, is there something new I should know about?

BTW, I'm using the *#bleedingEdge* version, with Magritte3 and all.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and it works fine in my example. 
What I did is this:

You have a Star, who has Planets, who at it's time points to the owner Star.

```
Star new 
    name: 'Sun';
    position: 10@12;
    addPlanet: (Planet new 
        name: 'Earth';
        orbit: 3;
        yourself);
    save
```

Both possible combinations works for me:

```
Star class>>#isVoyageRoot
    ^ true
Planet class>>#isVoyageRoot
    ^ true
```

and:

```
Star class>>#isVoyageRoot
    ^ true
Planet class>>#isVoyageRoot
    ^ false
```

So... I don't know where is your error :(

Comment: Your code also works for me, so I guess it's about something else in my model... at least now I know it's my fault! Thanks a lot :)